# StreamReader reads deleted file

Tags: c#

I am trying to search a directory for some filenames and want to output every file found. The filenames are listed in "files.txt".

The strange thing is, that I deleted the file with Windows Explorer from the disk, but it still outputs the content of the old file.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\files.txt", FileMode.Open)))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"ReadLine: \"{line}\"");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {           
            Directory.GetFiles(folder, line, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()
            .ForEach(s =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"FileFound: {s}");
             });
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening or what the cause of this is.

Comment: Maybe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Buffer? c&ache? different file /path?

Comment: Insert a `File.Delete("c:\\files.txt");` before the first line here. And then maybe we will believe you.

Comment: You deleted that "files.txt" file? Are you *sure* you deleted it from the correct location? Try specifying the full path instead of just the filename.

Comment: *"I have deleted the file from the disk"* - using windows explorer before starting software or how?

Comment: I see there is no path in your open, depending on how you execute your programme you can have different excecute path.

Comment: Debug/ realease/ Service/ double click on the exe may result in distinct execution context. meaning the relative path point to an other file.

Comment: My fault. It is an absolute path. For simplicity I have reduced the example. Sorry
Deleted the file with windows explorer.

Comment: @StefanH, it's ok . This is what comment are for. Editing your answer to add those information, as you did, is great.

Comment: Now convince us with a `File.Delete(<abspath>)`. See [mcve]

Comment: Could `StreamReader` load the entire text file in the memory, thus not needing the file anymore?

Comment: Probably it will work with File.Delete() but this doesn't solve my problem. I have to update the file regular but it doesnt use the updated file. And for testing purposes I have deleted the file

Comment: No, a StreamReader will not read/open a deleted file. So you didn't delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself now and just write this if someone has a similiar problem.

The file was deleted and the above code still worked.
The problem was Windows VirtualStore. There was a copy from an older version of the file.

It was working because the data from the VirtualStore is treated with priority. In the moment I deleted the file from there it was working as expected.